# Dependency in multidimensional marked point patterns

Tags: spatstat

As I understand, currently, if we have multi-type point pattern we can determine dependencies between points of various marks using functions like `Jmulti`, `Gmulti` etc.

Now, if each point is associated with multiple marks (say, as a data frame where each column is a mark variable) then how do we find dependency between points of different mark variables? Note that in this case, a point could have two different marks but have the same spatial coordinate.

I think in this case, the number of points having the same coordinates but different marks is in some sense a measure of dependency between the point patterns of different mark variables, but I am not sure if there are methods to do this analysis in `spatstat`.

Thanks for your clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is discussed in Chapter 15 of [the spatstat book](https://book.spatstat.org).

However I think you may be confusing two different things: (1) a point pattern in which each point carries several different mark variables, so that the marks for the pattern are represented by a data frame with one row for each point and one column for each mark variable; and (2) a marked point pattern in which there may be several points that have the same spatial coordinate but different mark values.
An example of (1) is the `finpines` dataset in `spatstat` in which each tree location is marked by the tree's height and diameter. An example of (2) would be a spatial pattern of road accidents in which each vehicle is represented by a point, so that two-vehicle accidents are represented by two points at the same location, perhaps with different labels.

To deal with (1), you could use functions like `Kmulti`, `Gmulti`, `Jmulti`. These functions always compare two groups of points, identified by the arguments `I` and `J` which can be logical vectors. You can define any two subsets of your point pattern as the subsets `I` and `J`. For example in the `finpines` data you could define `I <- with(marks(finpines), height > 10 * diameter)` which would select all the trees whose height in metres is greater than 10 times diameter in cm. and similarly make another, different rule for `J`.

Other ways of investigating dependence in marked point patterns include the mark correlation function `markcorr`, nearest neighbour correlation `nncorr`, the conditional moments `Emark`, `Vmark` and other tools described in Chapter 15.

Finally a caution that summary functions do not "determine" dependence; they are only measures of correlation.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. After I posted the question, I saw that Chapter 15 indeed deals with these types of marks. Yes, I do realize its only correlation.